# How do you count the distinct values for each day using a timestamp column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm using mysql and I'm having trouble thinking of a query to count the number of users/visitors for a certain date range. The way that I'm currently doing it is using php, I select the date range and process the data in a for loop and then just count them there. It's actually pretty easy, but the problem is that this method does not work for bigger data of a few million rows. The alternative is to count the distinct values using mysql only and just return a count and not actual data by utilizing the index on the timestamp column. Also, converting the column to a datetime is not an option. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Here's a sample result set of what I need:

```
date     | count
5-01-13     14
5-02-13     44
5-03-13     23
5-04-13     13
```

My problem is that I don't know how to group the timestamp column by day.

Comment: Where is the timestamp column you speak of? It's not shown here.

Comment: Are you happy with any of the answers? In case you need more help please ask, otherwise mark one of the answers as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: Non of the answers would work because they do a group by second. The reason being is that a timestamp records by the second, where I need to group the data by day.

Answer (score 5):

That should do the trick:

```
SELECT DATE('datetimecolumn'), COUNT(*) 
  FROM Table 
 GROUP BY DATE('datetimecolumn')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do the same, but instead add a group by clause:

```
SELECT myDate, count(distinct myField) as cnt
FROM myTable
WHERE myDate BETWEEN ? and ?
GROUP by myDate;
```

Where the "?" are the dates you use in your original query.